# What abstraction results from the static nesting of scopes, and does dynamic scoping support or ruin this layer of abstraction?

Tags: dynamic, scope, static, abstraction, scoping

This is a really difficult concept for me to wrap my head around, mainly because there's so many parts to it.

I understand what abstraction is. I also understand what dynamic and static scoping are.

However, what is the "static nesting of scopes"? (Is it even a real thing, or was my professor referencing just normal static scoping? His English isn't perfect, so perhaps there was a miscommunication) What abstraction does it give you?

And is that abstraction removed with dynamic scoping?